# How to create drop down list in tableau dashboards

Tags: tableau-api

How to create a “sheet selector” that gives the ability to select an individual sheet from the dashboard and replace all sheets with just the sheet selected.

Answer (score 6):

This workaround will work:

1. Select create parameter(Right click in data window to the left).
2. In parameter dialog box assign values as shown below:

   Data type : String
   Allowable values : List
   List of values : All, Sheet 1, Sheet 2, ..
   and give it a name
3. Create calculated field (Right click in data window to the left)
4. Give parameter name from step 2 in Formula text box.
5. For each sheet in workbook, drag calculation field created in step 4 into filters shelf and do as follows:

   1. in general tab, select custom value list
   2. type `All` in text box and click add item button. type particular sheet name and click add item.
6. create a dashboard
7. Right click on worksheet and select `Parameter` --> `Select a sheet`. You can find new filter added to your right side and you can select which sheet to show in dashboard.

   [Reference](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-sheet-selector-for-dashboard)

Comment: I can not find custom value list when I right click on the Filters shelf. How can I go to custom value list?